# Does spacecraft injection point and perigee coincide?

Tags: launch, orbit

When a `SpaceCraft` is injected into an `orbit`( either LEO/GTO ), does the `point of injection` coincide with that of the `perigee` of the resultant `orbit` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the point of injection may be any point along the ellipse of the orbit. It is *common* for it to be at or near the perigee, but there's no physical requirement that it be so.

Comment: @Russsell thanks!  In that case will matter if it is injected before or after `perigee`?